# Fortran equivalent to matlab find - application to slicing matrix without memory duplication

Tags: arrays, matlab, fortran

I use the command find quite a lot in matlab, and I wonder how to translate this smartly in fortran to extract a slice of an array. In matlab you can slice with either logicals or indexes, but in fortran you need indexes to slice. I'm aware of the intrinsic subroutines pack et al, but have never used them. Also, since I'm dealing with big matrices, I would like to avoid duplicating memory. I want the sliced matrix to be manipulated within a subroutine. I've read somewhere that slices of array were not duplicated. I don't know how this the slicing in done in matlab though. I'm puzzled also because in matlab some allocations are transparent to you.

I'd like to know how to reproduce the examples below, and make sure I'm not duplicating stuff in memory and that it's actually elegant to do so. Otherwise, I would forget about slicing and just send the whole matrix(since it's by reference) and loop through an index array I...

Matlab example 1: simply reproducing find

```
  v=[1 2 3 4];
  I=find(v==3);
```

Matlab example 2:

```
m=rand(4,4);
bools=logical([ 1 0 0 1]);
I=find(bools==1); 
% which I could also do like: 
I=1:size(m,1); 
I=I(bools);

  for i=1:length(I)
      % here dealing with m(I(i)),:)  and do some computation
      % etc.
```

Example 3: just call a subroutine on m(I,:) , but using directly booleans for slicing

```
   foo( m(bools, :) , arg2, arg3 )
```

In advance thank you for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fortran doesn't have an exact match for Matlab's `find` but you can generally use either `where` or `forall`, and sometimes both, to replace its functionality.

For example, given an array `v` such as you have in your first example, the Fortran statement

```
where (v==3) do_stuff
```

will operate only on the elements of `v` which are equal to 3.  This doesn't get you the indices of those elements as `find` does, but much of the use of `find` is for selecting elements for having stuff done to them, and in most of those cases the `where` construct is applicable.

Given `v` as before, and an index array `ix` which, in Fortran, is an array of logicals like this:

```
[.true., .false., .false., .true.]
```

you can use `ix`, so long as it is the same shape as `v`, in masked array assignments such as

```
where (ix) v = some_value
```

`ix` doesn't have to be an array of logicals, it can be an array of any type, if it were an array of reals you might have an expression such as

```
where (ix>=0.0) v = some_value
```

I don't think that any of the current Fortran compilers make copies of arrays to implement `where` constructs. I'll leave you to read about the `forall` construct.

Don't forget, either, that you can use arrays as indices for Fortran arrays, so the expression

```
v([1,3]) = 0
```

sets elements 1 and 3 of `v` to 0. You can, of course, use multiple array indices if your array has rank greater than 1.

When you start using this sort of indexing to pass non-contiguous sections of an array to a sub-program, then you have to start worrying about copying into temporary arrays (if that's the sort of thing that you want to worry about).  I believe that compilers may make temporary copies if you do something like

```
call my_subroutine(array(1:12:3, 2:12:4))
```

to enable the subroutine, which does not know the indices of the elements of the array section at run-time, to operate on what it 'sees' as a contiguous array.

Comment: Temporary array and copy-in, copy-out will be required for assumed size  dummy argument.

Comment: @Vladimir F - a temporary for "copy-in", maybe, but language rules restrict use of actual arguments with vector subscripts to situations where the dummy argument is not modified (this is a point that should perhaps be made in the answer), the processor will not have to "copy out".  Explicit shape and (given the typical implementation of an array descriptors) assumed shape arguments equally may require the temporary.

Comment: F2008's DO CONCURRENT is another language construct that allows operation on logical index masks, with more more flexibility than that offered by the masked assignment constructs.

Comment: If I have to find nth, or for simplicity, first instance of a condition then is loop the only way to go?

Answer (score 6):

You can use "pack" with an implied `do` loop:

```
I = pack([(j,j=1,size(v))],v==3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bellow, in FORTRAN CODE, is an example of a subroutine that makes the equivalent of find in matlab or scilab. In the examples below, we want to (a) find the position of the vector where the vector is equal to 22 (b)  find the positions of even numbers in a vector

```
     PROGRAM Principal
     REAL*8 A(8)
     INTEGER n, npos, pos(8)
     n=8
     A = (/ 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 /)
     ! Find the positions of vector A that is equal to 22 
     CALL FindInVector(n,A==22,npos,pos)
     WRITE(*,*) pos(1:npos)

     ! Find the positions of vector A that contains even numbers 
     CALL FindInVector(n,ABS(A/2.d0-INT(A/2.d0))<1.d-2,npos,pos)
     WRITE(*,*) pos(1:npos)

     END PROGRAM Principal
```

!________________________________________________________________

! Subroutine that find positions of a vector of logicals TF (True or False). The first npos elements contains the response.

```
     SUBROUTINE FindInVector(n,TF,npos,pos)
    ! Inlet variables
    INTEGER,INTENT(IN):: n      ! Dimension of logical vector
    LOGICAL,INTENT(IN):: TF(n)  ! Logical vector (True or False)
    ! Outlet variables
    INTEGER npos                ! number of "true" conditions
    INTEGER pos(n)              ! position of "true" conditions
    ! Internal variables
    INTEGER i                   ! counter
    INTEGER v(n)                ! vector of all positions

    pos = 0                     ! Initialize pos
    FORALL(i=1:n)   v(i) = i    ! Enumerate all positions
    npos  = COUNT(TF)           ! Count the elements of TF that are .True.
    pos(1:npos)= pack(v, TF)    ! With Pack function, verify position of true conditions

    ENDSUBROUTINE FindInVector
```

Comment: Instead of the `where` for `v=0` followed by `v/=0` in the pack, why not just `pack(v,tf)`?

Comment: `WHERE(TF.EQV..FALSE.)v=0 `  Testing a logical against either `.true.` or `.false.` always has that fresh newbie smell about it.  Simpler here is `WHERE(.not.tf)v=0 ` or, even better, follow @francescalus' advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler version is possible, see the subroutine below. The example shows how to find the values smaller than 0.1 in array x.

```
program test
   real,    dimension(:), allocatable :: x  
   integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: zeros

   x=[1.,2.,3.,4.,0.,5.,6.,7.,0.,8.]
   call find_in_array(x<0.01,zeros)
   write(*,*)zeros

   contains

   subroutine find_in_array(TF,res)

      ! Dummy arguments
      logical, dimension(:),              intent(in)   :: TF    ! logical array
      integer, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out)  :: res   ! positions of true 
                                                                ! elements
      ! Local arrays
      integer, dimension(:), allocatable  :: pos
   
      pos=[(i,i=1,size(TF))]
     !pos=[1:size(TF)]  ! valid on Intel compiler
      res=pack(pos,TF)

   end subroutine find_in_array

end program test
```

Comment: pos is the index of all elements in TF, after the pack call just the true elements. Isnan is an intrinsic fucntion that determines whether an array element is Not a Number, In the test routine nans is an array containing the indices to all NaN elements of .

Comment: sorry the nan was meant as not-a-number; you can read nan but not assign it, my bad.

Comment: the assignment pos=[1:size(TF)] is valid since 2003 I think. and no need to allocate.

Comment: @DanoRoelvink I don't think `pos=[1:size(TF)]` is valid. Do you mean `pos=[(i,i=1,size(TF))]`?

Comment: Did you really compile and test your code? `pos=[1:size(TF)] ` is not valid Fortran. Did you want `pos=[(i, i=1:size(TF))]`  ?

Comment: @Vladimir F I did and it compiles and runs without a problem on Intel compiler. An alternative is       pos=[(i, i=1,size(TF))    Note 1,size(TF) not 1:size(TF) in this implied do loop. Will look further since when pos=[1:size(TF)] is legal, it is nice and elegant and works on Intel...

Comment: OK just checked, it is not standard fortran, so the implied do loop is to be preferred.