# Fortran indexing similar as Matlab

Tags: indexing, fortran, gfortran

I have a T(60000x8) matrix in which I want to do sorting operation.

In Matlab I can create a sub-matrix where I am sorting the rows that have same value in column 8.

```
a1 = max(T(:,8)); x = [1.0:1:a1];

for i = 1.0:1:a1   
T1 = T(T(:, 8)== x(i), :);

end
```

This works perfectly and does my job.

But I want to perform the similar operation using Fortran.

I have tried the followings:

```
read(7,*) *(height(i,j),j=1,8)

k=maxval(height(:,8))

a1 = int(height(:,8))

allocate(x(k), T1(k,8))

do i=1,k

x(i) = i

end do

do i = 1, k

T1 = height((a1(i)== x(i)),:)

end do
```

When compiling this gives me error

```
Error: Array index at (1) must be of INTEGER type, found LOGICAL
```

Comment: Please, do not use **bold** formatting for code, use the `code` formatting, either using \` backticks or just using the buttons in the editor. It requires quite some effort to clean it up and is is probably still not correct, the indentation is probably still messed-up.

Comment: The code should be cleaned up more, as one of the comments suggests. its hard to tell where some of the loops begin and end

Comment: Probably relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691925/fortran-equivalent-to-matlab-find-application-to-slicing-matrix-without-memory/

Answer (score 1):

Fortran is not Matlab ;)... Matlab has a feature to extract a subarrays using booleans, Fortran has not. However Fortran has a sub-array indexing feature.

Your code has many flaws, and I have to assume that `height` and `T1` are real arrays. You can obtain your desired result (at least what I understand you want) with:

```
integer :: i
integer, allocatable :: idx(:)
real, allocatable :: x(:), T1(:,:)

a1 = nint(height(:,8))
x = [(i,i=1,size(a1))]
idx = pack( x, mask=(a1==x) )
T1 = height(idx(:),:)
```

Explanation, for instance:

```
       a1 : [4 2 3 1 5]
       x  : [1 2 3 4 5]
(a1 == x) : [F T T F T]
      idx : [  2 3   5]  ! 3 elements
```

`T1` will be made of the columns 2, 3, 5 of `height`